# Tex4ebook - cellspacing and cellpadding

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook, epub

my ebook created with tex4ebook contains cellspacing and cellpadding in tables. These attributes are not tolerated anymore (according to the ebookcheck). How can I remove them in the build process?

```
<div class='tabular'> <table class='tabular' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' id='TBL-3'><colgroup id='TBL-3-1g'><col id='TBL-3-1' /><col id='TBL-3-2' /><col id='TBL-3-3' /><col id='TBL-3-4' /><col id='TBL-3-5' /></colgroup><tr style='vertical-align:baseline;' id='TBL-3-1-'><td class='td11' id='TBL-3-1-1' style='white-space:nowr  ...
```

Kind regards

Hartmut

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{halignTB<>}{tabular}{%
\HCode{id="TBL-\TableNo" class="tabular"\Hnewline
   \GROUPS\Hnewline
 }<>\HAlign}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\Configure{halignTB<>}` command configures contents of HTML attributes that are used in the `<table>` element. I took this definition from TeX4ht source code and removed `cellspacing` and `cellpading`.

The following sample file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l| l|}
  \hline
  first & second\\
  \hline
  third & fourth\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
tex4ebook -c mycfg.cfg sample.tex
```

Produces this HTML code:

```html
<div class='tabular'> <table class='tabular' id='TBL-1'><colgroup id='TBL-1-1g'><col id='TBL-1-1' /></colgroup><colgroup id='TBL-1-2g'><col id='TBL-1-2' /></colgroup><tr class='hline'><td><hr /></td><td><hr /></td></tr><tr id='TBL-1-1-' style='vertical-align:baseline;'><td class='td11' id='TBL-1-1-1' style='white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;'>first</td><td class='td11' id='TBL-1-1-2' style='white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;'>second</td></tr><tr class='hline'><td><hr /></td><td><hr /></td></tr><tr id='TBL-1-2-' style='vertical-align:baseline;'><td class='td11' id='TBL-1-2-1' style='white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;'>third</td> <td class='td11' id='TBL-1-2-2' style='white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;'>fourth</td>
</tr><tr class='hline'><td><hr /></td><td><hr /></td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, this works, thank you. I have one additional question but I will ask it in a separate post as not related.